# Add data from one table to another

Tags: sql

I'm new at SQL I am stuck at this.
I have two tables
Table 1->4 Columns
Table 2->3 columns( 2 Same column names as in table 1)

**Table 1**

```
UserID    Email    Name     Pass
--------------------------------
xyz      abc@123   xyz      xyz
123      123@xyz   abc      123
```

**Table 2**

```
EmpID    Email    Name     
-----------------------
xyz      abc@123   xyz
```

**Result-Table2**

```
EmpID    Email    Name     
-----------------------
xyz      abc@123   xyz     
         123@xyz   abc
```

The table above are smaller ones, I have table with more than 60 columns. I want a method which can copy the common columns from table 1 to table 2.

Comment: What do you mean by copy? Can you give a more concrete example? How are the columns in Table2 related to Table1? Are the number of rows in the two tables the same?

Comment: which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I'll Edit my question.

Comment: The way I interpreted the question was that he wants to copy values from Table1 and Table 2 into a third table - is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Use an INNER JOIN to match related columns:

```
SELECT Table1.*, Table2.*
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2
ON Table1.UserID = Table2.EmpID AND Table1.Email = Table2.Email AND Table1.Name = Table2.Name
```

Comment: The problem is I am having nearly 30 columns in table 2, so writing each column name in set clause is not easy. Is there any way this could be done automatically?

Comment: Perhaps, but not easily within SQL. If this is a one-off task, I'd just bite the bullet and specify 30 columns in the join, otherwise, you can use a Python ORM or similar to better process the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the data you provided
You can  use update for copyiing data

```
Update table2
inner join table1 on table1.userID = table2.EmpID
set  email = table1.email, 
     name = table1,name ;
```

Comment: The problem is I am having nearly 30 columns in table 2, so writing each column name in set clause is not easy. Is there any way this could be done automatically?

Comment: This is  a suggestion for copy .. keep in mind that in some mysql id like toad  the column are suggested by ide itself then the problem for the type is minor ..  for the type i think is a problem related to the editing/ide  tools you are using .. .. I hope my answer and my suggestion are sueful for you ..

Answer (score 0):

this generates an insert of common columns.

```
declare 
@sql varchar(max),
@Columnlist varchar(max)


SELECT @Columnlist   =  coalesce(@Columnlist+'], ','') + '['+x.column_name 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS x 
join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS y 
on x.column_name = y.column_name
and y.TABLE_NAME =  'table2'
WHERE x.TABLE_NAME = 'table1'



set @sql ='select '+@Columnlist+'] from table1' 

insert into table2
exec(@sql)
```